# How to display my Image from a URL into my JLabel (JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Hello guys i am trying to display a picture from a URL on my JFrame,
but its not working. Here is the code below: Note that MYJ is the name
of my JLabel. I showed a tutorial here already but when I am  trying to work with it, it displays on a separate label that was already created.

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class MYPIX extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public void myFrame (){

    }

    /**
     * Creates new form MYPIX
     */
    public MYPIX() {
        initComponents();

            Image image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/xiVXrCD.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

                 ImageIcon I22 = new ImageIcon();
                        MYJ.setIcon(I22);
        }

    }

     public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MYPIX().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
     private javax.swing.JLabel MYJ;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: i'm not sure what are u asking but you have to pass image to imageicon like this `ImageIcon I22 = new ImageIcon(image);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your exception block will only be called if something goes wrong, instead, within the `try` block, you should be setting the lable's icon property after it's loaded successfully (because no error was raised during the `read` process, the following lines in the `try` block can be executed

```
 URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/xiVXrCD.jpg");
 image = ImageIO.read(url);
 MYJ.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Don't forget to add the `JLabel` to the frame.

You might also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: thanks a million, you are really mad at this, it workkkkkkkked!!

Comment: You are life saver

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that is working:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class MYPIX extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void myFrame (){

}

/**
 * Creates new form MYPIX
 */
public MYPIX() {
 //   initComponents();
try {
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/xiVXrCD.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    MYJ = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
    this.add(MYJ);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

         ImageIcon I22 = new ImageIcon();
                MYJ.setIcon(I22);
}

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new MYPIX().setVisible(true);
    }
});
}
private javax.swing.JLabel MYJ; 
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://1821662466.rsc.cdn77.org/images/google_apps_education.jpg"));
    imgLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img));

}
catch(IOException ex) {

}
```

You can try this method

Comment: I don't think this is clear enough. The question is not that the implementation doesn't work.